# Generic Iterator on Entry Set

Tags: java, generics

```
static <V> void myMethod(Map<?, V> map)
{
 Iterator<Entry<?, V>> it = map.entrySet().iterator();
}
```

I'm seeing below compilation error:
Type mismatch: cannot convert from `Iterator<Map.Entry<capture#5-of ?,V>>` to `Iterator<Map.Entry<?,V>>`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```
Iterator<? extends Entry<?, V>> it = map.entrySet().iterator();
```

The reason your attempt doesn't work is a bit hard to see, particularly because `Iterator<T>` does not consume any `T` (i.e. it doesn't have a method which takes a `T` as a parameter).

You can't assign an `Iterator<Entry<capture#5-of ?,V>>` to an `Iterator<Entry<?, V>>` for the same reason that you can't assign an `Iterator<Entry<Integer, String>>` to an `Iterator<Entry<?, V>>`.  The `capture#5` is just a name used to differentiate the specific `?` found in your method's parameter from other distinct wildcard instances.  It could just as easily be a concrete type.

The reason this doesn't work is more clear if instead of `Iterator` you think of a class like `List`.

```
List<Entry<Integer, String>> entries = new ArrayList<>();

//this is a compile error, but assume it is possible
List<Entry<?, String>> wildcardEntries = entries; 

//then since this is already possible
wilcardEntries.add(new Entry<String, String>("a", "b"));
Entry<Integer, String> entry1 = entries.get(0);

//this would result in a type error (ClassCastException)
Integer i = entry1.getKey();
```

By using `? extends Entry<?, V>` you're not exposing yourself to this, as you do not claim to know anything about the type of `Entry` your `Iterator` can consume, only what it can produce.

### Edit

Though Jiman deleted his answer, he had a good point that using the for-each loop is a lot cleaner approach (assuming you're just trying to iterate over the entries) that would avoid this issue entirely. This should work:

```
for ( Entry<?, V> entry : map.entrySet() ) {
   //...
}
```

Comment: But i can't use foreach, because the actual method is this:   `code`static <V> void fillMapValues(Map<?, V> map, Collection<? extends V> values, V defaultValue)
 {
  Iterator<? extends Entry<?, V>> it = map.entrySet().iterator();
  for (V value : values)
   it.next().setValue(value);
  while (it.hasNext())
   it.next().setValue(defaultValue);
 }`code`

Comment: @VenkataRaju: Fair enough, yes Iterator is the right approach then.  I assume that this code is meant for maps with a deterministic iteration order, like `LinkedHashMap` or `TreeMap`?  The order of elements in a `HashMap` is extremely hard to predict, and can completely change when you insert a new element.